# How to use maven repositories instead of p2 update sites to provision plugins in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi, p2

In my region it will be much faster using a maven repository instead of a p2 update site to provision plugins in Eclipse IDE and I'm craving for a solution. Has there been solutions already or can somebody drop some hints for me to modify the source code of the update mechanism so that a maven repository can fit in? I see that the DBeaver Universal Database Tool, which is an Eclipse RCP application, uses maven repositories to deliver database connection drivers. How can I achieve the same in provisioning of Eclipse plugins?

Comment: You are mixing two things here. Eclipse plugins, that are stored in p2 repositories and extend eclipse-based apps: DBeaver is an eclipse-rcp based app. And "applications plugin", in the case of DBeaver, database drivers ("plugins"). For the latter, those "dedicated extension to a specific eclipse-rcp based app") can be managed in any way, ie the way DBeaver coders  have programmed the feature, including downloading from maven repositories. There is code in DBeaver to manage such "dynamic app extension" that the user of the application can download

Comment: And DBeaver has a mechanism called "extensions" that can be installed to extend the eclipse-rcp based code itself. Those are "real" eclipse plugins and downloaded from p2 repositories as for other eclipse plugins

Answer (score 0):

Since Eclipse is based on the OSGi framework Equinox, and there are other OSGi frameworks that work well with Maven, e.g., Karaf, one possible solution will be managing the Eclipse plugins in Karaf.